# Javascript function not working currently

Tags: javascript, html-table, datatable

I have an HTML table where data is being displayed from the data table and where a function is being assigned with the use of an `ID TAG` that hides the `<td>` with the ID `private-mode` when you click on the button.

but the function only seems to work for the first row and not for the other rows I have checked the other rows with the inspect element function in chrome and they all have the ID `private-mode`

Can someone explain to me why its not working for the other rows?

Button:

```
<button onclick="privatemode()">Private mode</button>
```

html-table:

```
 <div class="cards card">
      <table class="table hoverTable">
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Omschrijving</th>
          <th>Bedrijf</th>
          <th>Betaalmethode</th>
          <th>Bedrag</th>
          
        </tr>
        
        <!-- PHP CODE TO FETCH DATA FROM ROWS -->
        <?php
            // LOOP TILL END OF DATA
            while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc())
            {
        ?>
        <tr>
          <!-- FETCHING DATA FROM EACH
                ROW OF EVERY COLUMN -->
          
          <th><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox"></th>
          <td><?php echo $rows['Omschrijving'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['Bedrijf'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['Betaalmethode'];?></td>
          <td id="private-mode"><?php echo $rows['Bedrag'];?></td>

          
          
          
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
      </table>
  
      </div>
```

Javascript:

```
   function privatemode() {
  var x = document.getElementById("private-mode");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `id` attribute is used to specify a unique id for an HTML element. You cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document. In your case, you seem to have multiple rows with same `id`. So your function always picks the first row. To change your working, you can use a common `class` name as a workaround to hide the content.

Here's an example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('private-mode');
  for (let element of elements) {
    if (element.style.display === "none") {
      element.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      element.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table hoverTable">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Omschrijving</th>
    <th>Bedrijf</th>
    <th>Betaalmethode</th>
    <th>Bedrag</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" /></th>
    <td>Sample</td>
    <td>Sample</td>
    <td>Sample</td>
    <td class="private-mode">Content 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" /></th>
    <td>Sample</td>
    <td>Sample</td>
    <td>Sample</td>
    <td class="private-mode">Content 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="myFunction()">Private mode</button>
```

Comment: Thanks it works! the only problem now is that the when the <td> is hidden the <td> moves to the left and when the <td> is showed it moves a bit back to the right but does not change back to the current position before the button was pressed.

Comment: Oh then you can use `visibility` instead of `display`. [Here's](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hide-or-show-html-elements-using-visibility-property-in-javascript/#:~:text=The%20visibility%20property%20is%20used,element%2C%20unlike%20the%20display%20property.) an example.

Comment: It works had to play around for a bit until I found out that I had to change the "none" and the "block" also but it works perfectly now! and learned something new today what is always a good thing so yeah thank you for taking your time to help me! and have a lovely day our night.